# SQL search result ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table call objects which there are the columns:

```
object_id, 
name_english(vchar), 
name_japanese(vchar), 
name_french(vchar), 
object_description
```

for each object.

When a user perform a search, they may enter either english, japanese or french... and my sql statement is:

```
SELECT  
 o.object_id,  
 o.name_english,
 o.name_japanese,  
 o.name_french,  
 o.object_description  
FROM 
 objects AS o
WHERE 
 o.name_english LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%') OR 
 o.name_japanese LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%') OR 
 o.name_french LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%')    
ORDER BY 
 o.name_english, o.name_japanese, o.name_french ASC
```

And some of the entries are like:

```
Tin spoon,  
Tin Foil,  
Doctor Martin Shoes,  
Martini glass,  
Cutting board,  
Ting Soda.
```

So, when the user search the word "Tin" it will return all results of these, but instead I just want to return the results which specific include the term "Tin" or displaying the result and rank them by relevance order. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MySQL FULLTEXT indices to do that. This requires the MyISAM table type, an index on (name_english, name_japanese, name_french, object_description) or whatever fields you want to search on, and the appropriate use of the MATCH ... AGAINST operator on exactly that set of columns.

See the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html, and the examples on the following page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Thanks, but since I am new to this, please mind my naive question.  As I am just comparing/searching for names of object, some people told me it is not necessary to use FULLTEXT unless it is a paragraph of text, this I am not sure.  And will converting the table to MYISAM/FULLTEXT affect the performance/speed? I have read many articles but none really explain my case.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: FULLTEXT is an index type. An index is a data structure that speeds up data access (search). The specific index type FULLTEXT gives you speedy access to all kind of VARCHAR, CHAR or TEXT fields based on a full (not partial) word. This matches your problem statement completely. Try it out and benchmark it. Converting a table from InnoDB to MyISAM has performance and size effects, especially if you have many concurrent writes on it. Also benchmark this. You might want to make the searchable columns a separate tables in a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation... and since the table will only update/has write operation  maybe once a week, so i guess the affect should be minimal =)  i will head on to try. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

After running the query above , you will get all sort of results including ones that you are not interested, but you can then use regular expressions on the above results(returned by mysql server) set to filter out what u need.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - you may have to filter out duplicates, but the basic idea is obvious.

```
    SELECT  
    `object`.`object_id`,  
    `object`.`name_english`,
    `object`.`name_japanese`,  
    `object`.`name_french`,  
    `object`.`object_info`, 1 as ranking   
    FROM `objects` AS `object`
    WHERE `object`.`name_english` LIKE CONCAT(:search,'%') OR `object`.`name_japanese` LIKE CONCAT(:search,'%') OR `object`.`name_french` LIKE CONCAT(:search,'%')
union 
    SELECT  
    `object`.`object_id`,  
    `object`.`name_english`,
    `object`.`name_japanese`,  
    `object`.`name_french`,  
    `object`.`object_info`, 10 as ranking   
    FROM `objects` AS `object`
    WHERE `object`.`name_english` LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%') OR `object`.`name_japanese` LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%') OR `object`.`name_french` LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%') 
ORDER BY ranking, `object`.`name_english`, `object`.`name_japanese`, `object`.`name_french` ASC
```